# Using a class instance created in one method from an another method

Tags: vb.net, winscp, winscp-net

I've been fumbling with WinSCP for a few days here now, and all I am missing is to "Open the Session" correctly.

Here the `Session` is initialized.

```
Private Sub Loginbutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Loginbutton.Click
    mySession = New Session()
    Dim mySessionOptions As New SessionOptions
    With mySessionOptions
        .Protocol = Protocol.Sftp
        .HostName = "192.168.0.247"
        .UserName = "usr"
        .Password = "pw"
        .SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa KEY"
    End With
    Using mySession As Session = New Session
        mySession.Open(mySessionOptions)
    End Using
    Form1.Show()

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

On the following form I need to use the `Session` again, and here I used the

```
Public Sub Open(ByVal sessionOptions As SessionOptions)
    Me.Show()

    For Each i As RemoteFileInfo In mySession.ListDirectory("/Database/").Files
        Objectlist1.Items.Add(i.Name)
    Next
    Objectlist1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

This right here works.
Which seems to open the session as required at this point. But my problem comes where I need to open the session multiple times in the same Form, as it does not Stay open by itself, if that's even possible.

Anything else I need to do in the application, is unable to open the Session as I cannot have several "Public Sub Open" down the line. If there is any WinSCP people here, can I make the session stay alive until application is closed? Any smart way of "Opening the Session" several times on the same form?

I find it hard to explain.

Example:
I have a ticker/timer, which refreshes the List located on Form 1 (Objectlist1)
And it ticks every 5.th second.

Here's the code used:

```
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick

    Objectlist1.Clear()
    For Each i As RemoteFileInfo In mySession.ListDirectory("/Database").Files
        Objectlist1.Items.Add(i.Name)
    Next
End Sub
```

Problem is though, when it ticks, I get 
Session is not opened, `System.InvalidOperationException` which basically is.. Session is not opened.. Now, Since its opened further up in the form, I apparently need to open it again? Or can I change something in the 
`Public Sub Open(ByVal sessionOptions As SessionOptions)` to make it able to stay alive all through the form, or?

Any advise here guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are initializing a presumably global variable or class field `mySession`, as you got advised at [Initialize Global Variable .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28769066/850848):

```
    mySession = New Session()
```

But then you declare a local variable with the same name (which hides the global one for the rest of the scope):

```
    Using mySession As Session = New Session
```

and you open *the local one*:

```
        mySession.Open(mySessionOptions)
```

and *immediately close it*:

```
    End Using
```

The global `mySession` is *never* opened.

You need to do:

```
    mySession = New Session()

    mySession.Open(mySessionOptions)
```

Comment: Ey Martin, Yea I thought it was something like that. 
I've done all you've advised so far, but the .Open(mySessionOptions) comes up on other forms as not Declared. 
See, In the first one, where I logged in remember, everything works fine. In the other forms, New Session works, but mySession.Open(mySessionOptions) is not declared for some reason.

Am I missing something in a module?

Comment: Well, then the `mySession` has to be project-wide. See [Declare global variables in Visual Studio 2010 and VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529862/declare-global-variables-in-visual-studio-2010-and-vb-net)

Comment: Project-Wide! There is something that might work. Right, I'll check that out, and see how it goes ;D

Thanks Prikryl!

Comment: Yeaah, that didn't work that well. Using Global Variables just renders "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." And before it was "Session not opened". Class is as it should be according to your instructions, and I have to use the Module ; Friend Module Module1
    Public mySession As Session
End Module, cos if Not the "Session" is rendered Undeclared.
Idk Martin, it doesn't seem to work well together. Only reason the program is even starting, is cus of "Public Sub Open" which can only be used 1 time pr Winform. Either I am given wrong info, or something else is messed up.

Comment: I assume you didn't remove the form-specific `mySession`, so it hides the global one.

Comment: I've used GlobalVariables.mySession to sort of guide it towards the Class. But I get the same errors on the same line of code.
Isn't this what you mean?
mySession.Open(GlobalVariables.mySessionOptions)  
And the GlobalVariables Class is; 
Public Class GlobalVariables
    Public Shared mySessionOptions As SessionOptions
    Public Shared mySession As Session
End Class

Comment: On what line does it throw? Note that it makes no sense to move `SessionOptions` to global scope. It's just `Session` that is used globally.

Comment: SessionOptions Removed.
It throws here;
Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        GlobalVariables.mySession = New Session()
        mySession.Open(GlobalVariables.mySessionOptions)


mySession.Open(GlobarVariables....

Comment: Wait, that was messed up.. It throws Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        GlobalVariables.mySession = New Session()
        [mySession.Open(GlobalVariables.mySessionOptions)] HERE

Comment: Did I provide wrong information? Need anything else?

Comment: 1) You still refer to global namespace in `mySession.Open(GlobalVariables.mySessionOptions)`. 2) You are not supposed to open the session in every method, just refer to the `mySession` variable. 3) Sorry, but this is getting nowhere. I suggest your starting learning programming on some easier task.

Comment: Well, I am not the most experienced person here, but it seems to be that WinSCP works best in only one WinForm and not projectwide.
I have followed  your recipe on making it Projectwide but its only WinSCP errors I get.
All examples on your website is one form only, and I would like to be able to do all my stuff in One form, but thats not what the application will be used for. And I have followed them to the last dott.

WinSCP does work in only one form however, exactly as the example x)
I appreciate the help provided so far, but I am rendered stuck regardless on NullReference :/